Python library face-recognition not installing on raspberry pi 3
I am trying to install face-recognition library for python on raspberry pi 3. But it's not installing, every time i try to install it gives the following error as shown in the given image.
Error on installation of library.
Whatever i do, its the same as it is.
Some settings of my system,
Hardware : Raspberry Pi 3 model A+
OS : Raspbian OS, a Debian based distro of Linux
Python version : 3.11.3
face-recognition lib version : 1.3.0
I am installing library in a virtual environment.
I ran the following commands. All of these, I found, from the internet.

This is due to maybe some cached installations are causing the issue.
pip install --no-cache-dir face-recognition

If the setuptools are of older version, that can be an issue.
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

Installing the dependencies from face-recognition separately.
pip install cmake dlib

After that, I tried to install the library by, first cloning the repo, and then install from the local.
git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git cd face_recognition pip install .

The previous one also didn't worked. so, I found that one. If there is a network issue, maybe large amount of data isn't downloaded at once, so, first download a small part of it, and then fetch the complete repo.
$ git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git --depth 1 $ cd face_recognition $ git fetch --unshallow

Then at last, I tried downloading using ssh. and it didn't worked.
$ git clone git@github.com:ageitgey/face_recognition.git


First I also tried installing using the apt package manager, but it also didn't worked. So, I created a virtualvenv. I am expecting the library to be installed.

In what order did you execute the commands? Did you try to first run pip install --upgrade pip, and then the others? What is the pip version after the upgrade? ( pip --version)

@AME Here's the pip version, pip 23.2.1.

And yes, the pip version was same before and after updating. It was already updated. First I ran all the commands before update, then, I ran the update command, and then executed all of the commands after updating.
